# Change Header Title depending on button pressed React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a page with two buttons... PRofile create button and PRofile Edit Button. they all point to the same page and the same form on another page. when it is edit pressed, the form is filled with info and can be edited if it is the create new profile btn pressed then the page loads with the form empty.

I want the Page Hader to change once the component loads depending on which button was pressed on the previous page.

This is what I have in the App.js:

````
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator headerMode='screen'>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="AgentAddEditPatient" component={AgentAddEditPatientPage} options={{ title:  'Add/Edit Patient' }} />
  );
}```

This is what I have on the page with the buttons:


```class AgentPatientsPage extends React.Component {


  
    launchAddPatientPage = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AgentAddEditPatient');


    launchEditPatientPage = (patient) => {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setFullYear(patient.birthYear, patient.birthMonth, patient.birthday);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AgentAddEditPatient', {
            'id': patient.id,
            'name': patient.name,
            'sex': patient.sex,
            'pictureUrl': patient.pictureUrl,
            'bloodGroup': patient.bioData ? patient.bioData.bloodGroup : null,
            'genotype': patient.bioData ? patient.bioData.genotype : null,
            'height': patient.bioData ? patient.bioData.heightInCm : null,
            'weight': patient.bioData ? patient.bioData.weight : null,
            'allergies': patient.bioData ? patient.bioData.allergies : null,
            'birthDate': date,
        });
    }
    }```

the two buttons:

```<TouchableOpacity style={styles.topLinkBtn} activeOpacity={.5} onPress={this.launchAddPatientPage}>
                            <Text style={styles.addLink}>Add New Patient</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity> 

<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => this.launchEditPatientPage(patient)}>
                                                <Image
                                                    style={styles.backButtonImage}
                                                    source={require('../assets/images/icon_edit.png')}
                                                />
                                            </TouchableOpacity>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AgentAddEditPatient',{'name': 'Add'});
this.props.navigation.navigate('AgentAddEditPatient',{'name': 'Edit'});

// in AgentAddEditPatient component constructor add this code below:
 
 constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);    
     this.state = { 
        pageName:this.props.navigation.state.params.name
     }
     
    //Then use state variable on the page render to change title like

    render() {
        return( <Text>{this.state.pageName</Text>}
    )
```